# PHP watermark does not save to the destination folder, but original image do

Tags: php, mongodb, watermark

I'm trying to write a simple php gallery with file upload. I want 3 files for each photo - original, smaller size and a watermarked one.

Saving the original photo works fine, but the watermarked image is not present in the folder after uploading. I have permission to write in this folder and even though I tried using `chmod` to force it, it is not working properly.

I also need to generate an image in 200x125px for the server, but couldn't do it, because the watermark is not working properly.

How can I achieve this?

```
<?php
  require '../vendor/autoload.php';

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
    $fileAuthor = $_POST['author'];
    $fileTitle = $_POST['title'];
    $conn = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://localhost:27017');


    $db = $conn->images;


    $collection = $db->uimages;
    $allowed = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
        if ($fileError === 0){
            if ($fileSize < 1024000){
                $fileNameID = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestFolder = '../images/'.$fileNameID;  
                $image = $_FILES['file'];;


                $fontSize = 4;

                $text = $_POST['watermark'];


                $xPosition = 10;
                $yPosition = 10;

                $newImg = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

                $fontColor = imagecolorallocate($newImg, 255, 0, 0);

                imagestring($newImg, $fontSize, $xPosition, $yPosition, $text, $fontColor);


                $save = "../images/". "water".$fileNameID .".png";
                chmod($save,0755);
                imagepng($newImg, $save, 0, NULL);
                imagedestroy($newImg);

               // move_uploaded_file($newImg, $fileDestFolder);

                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestFolder);
                $imageu = [
                    '_id' => $fileNameID,
                    'author' => $_POST['author'],
                    'title' => $_POST['title'],
                  ];
                     $collection->insertOne($imageu);
                header("Location: ../wheels.php?uploadsuccess");


            } else {
                echo "The image size is too big";
            }
        } else {
            echo "There was an error with the image";
        }

    } else {
        echo "You can not use this file extension";
    }


  }

?>
```

Comment: Is `move_uploaded_file($newImg, $fileDestFolder);` supposed to be commented out?

Comment: I tried with and without it with no success, so I left it commented out here. Thought that imagepng will save the image to the $save folder

Comment: Are you checking error logs to see if you get any permission errors?

Comment: Yep, I get actually no message there. It's like the file is saved, but not to the folder I'm pointing. Or isn't saved at all. I don't really know what's wrong.

Comment: You still stuck? I can look into this further if you like

Comment: Yep, I'm still stuck. I need to go to sleep right now, cause it's midnight. If you have time, I really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line `$image = $_FILES['file'];;` (aside from having two semi-colons - remove one of them!) is defining `$image` as the array given by `$_FILES['file']`. You already know this is an array, as you are accessing its properties at the top of the page.

You are then passing this array into `imagecreatefromjpeg()`, which is expecting a filepath. You should pass it `$fileTmpName` instead.

**Edit:** Added slightly condensed, 100% complete verifiable code (without the MongoDB stuff and header redirect) complete with form so you can test:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
    $fileAuthor = $_POST['author'];
    $fileTitle = $_POST['title'];

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
        if ($fileError === 0) {
            if ($fileSize < 1024000) {
                $fileNameID = uniqid('', true) . "." . $fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = '../images/' . $fileNameID;

                $fontSize = 4;

                $text = $_POST['watermark'];

                $xPosition = 10;
                $yPosition = 10;

                $newImg = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileTmpName);
                $fontColor2 = imagecolorallocate($newImg, 255, 0, 0);

                imagestring($newImg, $fontSize, $xPosition, $yPosition, $text, $fontColor2);

                $save = "../images/" . "water" . $fileNameID . ".png";

                imagepng($newImg, $save, 0, null);
                imagedestroy($newImg);

                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
            } else {
                echo "The image size is too big";
            }
        } else {
            echo "There was an error with the image";
        }
    } else {
        echo "You can not use this file extension";
    }

}
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<label>Watermark</label><input type="text" name="watermark"><br>
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

There are a few other problems with the code (e.g. you should check the filetype by mime type, not file extension, and an uploaded jpeg will end up with the filename water{uuid}**.jpg.png**), but your question should at least be answered.

Comment: I've passed the fileTmpName variable to this function, but still can not get the file saved there. Also tried uncommenting move uploaded file function, no effect either. I'm actually getting crazy while I can not figure out something this simple.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` has special checks which make sure the file was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism, so it shouldn't work for any other file which was not just uploaded. I tried your code but with `imagecreatefromjpeg($fileTmpName)`, it seemed to create the 'water...{uuid}.png as expected, however it didn't have the watermark. I'll have another look, see what's up.

Comment: It's actually working fine, I didn't give it a watermark which is why it wasn't working. I've condensed your code down to a single script, which should work as expected, assuming there's a folder in the parent directory called 'images' and you have correct permissions to create images there. I'll add some working code to the answer soon.

Comment: Indeed it works, I see my mistake Now. And thanks for the mime info, I will implement this